# Android Studio strange Layout errors probably bugs

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Strange things in Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 22, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

I have two layouts that looks the same(using exactly the same classes) , one is shown ok and the other is not visible at all. They both have the same Android Studio Design error like

[image: sdds]

This two layouts are list items in a `RecyclerView`, so one is visible and the other is not, very confusing. I have tried Invalidate cache/and restart.. but no change
The errors are:

> java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.next(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:302)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getInternalComplexColor(ResourceHelper.java:171)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColorStateList(ResourceHelper.java:223)
>     at
>   android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColor(BridgeTypedArray.java:300)
>     at
>   com.port.android.ui.chat.chatmessageView.ChatMessageView.initialize(ChatMessageView.java:86)
>     at
>   com.port.android.ui.chat.chatmessageView.ChatMessageView.(ChatMessageView.java:72)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

and:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: mDrawable cannot be null   at
>   com.gotcreations.emojilibrary.model.layout.EmojiSpan.getDrawable(EmojiSpan.java:45)
>     at
>   android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan.getCachedDrawable(DynamicDrawableSpan.java:116)
>     at
>   android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan.getSize(DynamicDrawableSpan.java:77)
>     at android.text.TextLine.handleReplacement(TextLine.java:898)   at
>   android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1054)   at
>   android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:417)   at
>   android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:307)   at
>   android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:281)   at
>   android.text.BoringLayout.isBoring(BoringLayout.java:294)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8125)   at
>   android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)   at
>   android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>     at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>     at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>     at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)   at
>   android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035)   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>     at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:22071)   at
>   android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:22035) Copy stack to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below line.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: mDrawable cannot be null   at com.gotcreations.emojilibrary.model.layout.EmojiSpan.getDrawable(EmojiSpan.java:45)
```

check youtr EmojiSpan.java line number 45. your drawable is null.

Comment: Yea I know, the problem is that the layout is working and displayed ok.  The layout having the `com.gotcreations.emojilibrary` is working, but Android Studio display this so it must be a bug

Comment: Can you share your project so that i can look into the problem if possible